# Unable to decode json string from Dictionary object in same order and sequence in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift3, cryptography, md5

I have created a Dictionary with some values. I want to create JSON string of that dictionary object.

I am using **String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!** to create json string but every time i run this code i am getting json string in diffrent sequence and order of same data.

```
import Foundation
import CommonCrypto

var object = ["emp1":["name":"neeraj","age":"14","degree":"Btech"],
          "emp2":["name":"ajay","age":"24","degree":"Mca"],
"emp3":["name":"vijay","age":"34","degree":"Bca"],
"emp4":["name":"raju","age":"44","degree":"Mtech"]]


if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: []){
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
}
```

**First time result:**

{"emp2":{"age":"24","degree":"Mca","name":"ajay"},"emp4":{"age":"44","name":"raju","degree":"Mtech"},"emp3":{"degree":"Bca","name":"vijay","age":"34"},"emp1":{"degree":"Btech","name":"neeraj","age":"14"}}

**Second time result:**

{"emp1":{"age":"14","degree":"Btech","name":"neeraj"},"emp4":{"name":"raju","degree":"Mtech","age":"44"},"emp3":{"name":"vijay","age":"34","degree":"Bca"},"emp2":{"name":"ajay","age":"24","degree":"Mca"}}

I want same result for every time.

I need same order to create md5 checksum to compare with recieved checksome of data.

I am getting a response from web service
 for e.g

```
{
"payload":{
"object1":["name":"neeraj"],
"object2":["name":"ajay"]
},
"hash":"<hash of payload using md5>"
}
```

i have to create an md5 hash at my side and need to verify with hash i recieved.

but when i create JSON String i got different order and my hash doesn't match with recieved hash.

Please help

Comment: Dictionary aren't ordered. You shouldn't care.

Comment: so is it possible ?

I need same order to create md5 checksum to compare with recieved checksome of data. @Larme

Comment: Check the options in `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:options:)`, but you shouldn't care about order. If you do care about order, you might be interested in array instead of dictionary then.

Comment: i got your point. but do you have any solution to create checksome of recieved json object from API service.

Comment: It is not possible using any built-in JSON encoder on iOS. If you care about dictionary order it cannot be solved without encoding by hand. (But the MD5 is over the literal bytes of the data. So I don't understand the question. Your code doesn't include an MD5 anywhere.)

Comment: If possible (iOS 11+) you can use `.sortedKeys` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/writingoptions/2888322-sortedkeys).

Comment: @RobNapier, i am getting a response from web service
 for e.g 
{
"payload":{
"object1":["name":"neeraj"],
"object2":["name":"ajay"]]
},
"hash":"<some hash using md5>"
}

i have to create an md5 hash at my side and need to verify with hash i recieved.

but when i create JSON String i got different order and my hash doesn't match with recieved hash.

Comment: I have updated my question please review and if possible please help. Thanks

Comment: @Larme .sortedkeys will not helpful. because i dont know the order of checksum created by server.

Comment: First, @Larme thank you. That is really useful (not here, but still). To the question, you will need to parse this by hand based on *precisely* how the server intends it. There is no way to MD5 "JSON data" in an abstract way. Extra newlines are not a problem in JSON. They're a major problem in MD5. You'll need to decode this by hand, and apply MD5 the exact way the server intends you to. I can't guess what that is. (I guess you could hire me, but I can't from what you're described here; it depends on the precise server code.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use MD5 it's broken.
2. Create your dictionary from the JSON parse and then instantiate **objects** from that dict.
3. Hash the objects with a sensible digest such as Keccak, SHA-2, SHA-3 or Blake2.